# Problems with JQueryUI dialog in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser

Hi people i have a problem rendering a jquery dialog box in firefox. The form dialog is supposed to open/show when a 'get-form' button is clicked. This works for all the other browsers except Firefox where the dialog content is already being displayed as a normal form.

this is a screenshot of the page in firefox. >> http://wyntersunholidays.com/screenshot.jpg

working as desired in safari. >> http://wyntersunholidays.com/Screen%20shot-safari.jpg

Also for some reason the button is not rendering as a jquery button. Can someone help shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance

```
 $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );  
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 350,
        left:200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Details": function() {
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + tel.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
```

This is how i include my scripts

```
<link href="css/learnercss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery-ui-1/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script> 


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

//the jquery...

})
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like the dialog isn't getting initiated. Please share some code.

Comment: i've re-edited the original question. its really weird and ive spent hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button does not render as a UI button too, it seems like Firefox does not accept how you include the JavaScript on your page. This is how I include jQuery and UI in a page:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    ...
</head>
```

Could you post how you include them, if it still doesn't work this way?

Comment: The original question has been updated to show how i included them.

Comment: and @Lawrence88:  It may have no bearing on your issue but it's best to put them at the bottom of the `<body>` element.  [Here's why.](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)

Comment: @Lawrence88: Ok, this should work. I guess the error must must really be in some JavaScript, as you suspected. Have you tried visiting your page in Firefox with Firebug running? This should give you an error in the console.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys. I downloaded and installed Firebug and firequery and was able to debug and fix the errors.

Comment: And the solution was?